# Base64 Image Size variation while saving

Tags: java, android, image, macos, size

I am creating one application which downloads the images in base64 string format and save it in an image file while downloading data.

My application is available on two platforms: iOS/Android and PC/Mac

The problem is when I downloading the images and saving those on disk I am getting a size difference. In mobile it is downloading the exact size which I have uploaded but on my mac its size is greater than the actual size. Why the size of image in mac is greater than that of actual size downloaded?

Comment: image can view correctly on iOs ans other device?

Comment: Yes image is viewing correctly. One thing here is on iOS and Android size of image is same as that I have uploaded. In mac its size getting increased but image is opening successfully.

Comment: That depends on the way you decode the base64 string and then save the resulting bytes as file. If you don't show code you cannot be helped.

Comment: `its size getting increased`. Please be more specific. Tell all sizes involved.

Comment: @greenapps: Your hint has saved hours. I have observed that if I use ByteArrayInputStream and Bufferred Image and ImageIO class then it is saving the image in high resolution. Now I am using the class FileOutputStream to write the content in file. Its keeping the size same as uploaded. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in some of operating system maybe file size were difference, and its not problem if, for example your images view correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that if I use

```
ByteArrayInputStream and Bufferred Image and ImageIO
```

class then it is saving the image in high resolution. Now I am using the class

```
FileOutputStream
```

to write the content in file. Its keeping the size same as uploaded.